# Using checkboxes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

I am trying to figure out how to get the value of only the checkboxes that have been selected. I will have about ten more checkboxes with a Submit UIButton. When the Submit button is pressed I will be saving all the values for only the selected checkmarks. The code I have now will not print "Boxing and Karate" it only will print "Boxing" when Boxing is selected.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR2Aq.png)

```
class SignUpSecondViewController: UIViewController, BEMCheckBoxDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var wrestling: BEMCheckBox!
@IBOutlet weak var karate: BEMCheckBox!
@IBOutlet weak var boxing: BEMCheckBox!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    boxing.delegate = self
    karate.delegate = self
    wrestling.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

  func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {

    if (checkBox.tag == 1 && checkBox.on){
        print("BOXING")
    }else if (checkBox.tag == 1 && checkBox.on) && (checkBox.tag == 2 && checkBox.on){
        print("Boxing and karate")

    }

}
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You can keep all your checkboxes in an array and traverse them whenever `submit` button is pressed. Or you can keep a dictionary, where whenever a button is turned on, it adds its value, and upon turning off, it removes it's value.

Comment: Like it is it will always satisfy your first condition and won't fall through the second one.

Comment: @LeoDabus Even without the first one, the 2nd can never be true. `checkBox` can't have more than one tag value at the same time.

Comment: you can create a collection of your all three UIButtons. it will be [UIButton]. and give the tag for 0, 1 and 2. give same IBAction for all three buttons check in action sender with tag and Make selected to the respective button and and deselected remaining two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are just checking `checkBox` and you are comparing `checkBox` tag 1 and 2 at same time. It always gives you false. According to requirement, make a global variable of type Array `options` , use these lines of code:

```
    var options = [String]()
func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
    switch checkBox {
    case wrestling:
      addRemoveOption(forState: checkBox.on, option: "WRESTLING")
    case karate :
        addRemoveOption(forState: checkBox.on, option: "KARATE")
    default:
        addRemoveOption(forState: checkBox.on, option: "BOXING")
    }

}
func addRemoveOption(forState : Bool , option : String)
{
    switch forState
    {
    case true:
        options += [option]
    case false:
        if let index = options.index(of: option)
        {
            options.remove(at: index)
        }

    }
}
@IBAction func actionSubmit(_ sender : Any)
{
    print(options.joined(separator: "&"))
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: how would I get these selected values once submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of Bools. Set them all to false to start, as well as setting your checkboxes to the off state. (Let's call the array buttonStates)

In your IBAction, use sender.tag-1 as an index into your array of Bools and set the selected bool based on the button state.

When the user taps the submit button, walk through the array of Bools and query them for the current button states.

Note that tags are not an ideal way to do this since it's fragile. If you have other views in your view hierarchy with the same tag numbers then the results will be undefined.

Putting your buttons in a `UIStackView` and then finding them in the stack view's 'arrangedViews` array to figure out their index is cleaner, plus the stack view makes it very easy and clean to position as many check boxes as you want either horizontally or vertically.